# How change background color in React Native when NOT using SafeAreaView?

Tags: react-native, safeareaview

How can I change the color of the “iPhone app switcher” bottom bar here:

[image: app switcher bar]

I want to build a fullscreen app so I’m not using `SafeAreaView`.

This is my main screen/layout component:

```
const Screen = (props: any): React.ReactElement => {
  const { backgroundColor = 'white' } = props
  return (
    <>
      <View
        style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor }]}
      >
        <StatusBar
          backgroundColor={backgroundColor === 'black' ? 'black' : 'white'}
          barStyle={backgroundColor === 'black' ? 'light-content' : 'dark-content'}
        />
        {props.children}
      </View>
    </>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
})
```

Comment: It was enough to add a `flex: 1 ` to the view style of screen for the code that you have provided. I do not believe that this is sufficient for your scenario. Can you share the complete code in order to reproduce the scenario in your provided images?

Comment: @DavidScholz Thank you! I actually had `flex:1` already, see updated code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just need to change the tab bar `backgroundColor` like this

```
 <MainTab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarStyle:{
          backgroundColor:"black" //like this
        }
      }}>

  {...MaintabScreens}

</MainTab.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Flex:1` should work in this case however you can Try Giving device height as the height it might solve the issue

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    height: Dimensions.get('screen').height,
    width: Dimensions.get('screen').width,
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
})
```

Edit: on second thought did you give SafeAreaView to your bottom tab? can you share your bottom tab code?

also, you have your background color set to `"white"` so it should display white if you don't pass any background color try changing it to `"black"`

```
const { backgroundColor = 'white' } = props
```